# Why int (&func())[5]; works but int (*func())[5]; is invalid?

Tags: c++, syntax

They seems to be the same declarations to me...

Comment: Why do you think `int (*func())[5]` is invalid?

Comment: They're not the same, but they are both valid.

Comment: *Don't be vague, be an [ace](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints); write a [proper](http://sscce.org/) [test-case!](http://www.xs4all.nl/~weegen/eelis/iso-c++/testcase.xhtml)*  What code have you tried where you get this error?

Answer (score 5):

Both work, but they do very different things, just like references and pointers do very different things. That "very" depends on who you talk to, but everyone agrees they are different.

```
int (&ref())[5];
int (*point())[5];

int (&var_ref)[5] = ref();
int (*var_point)[5] = point();
```

And with identical meaning using a typedef, which might make it clearer:

```
typedef int int5[5];

int5& ref();
int5* point();

int5 &var_ref = ref();
int5 *var_point = point();

int5 a;  // array declaration!
int5& ref() { return a; }
int5* point() { return &a; }

int main() {
  cout << var_ref[0] << '\n';       // prints 0
  cout << (*var_point)[0] << '\n';  // prints 0
}
```

Notice the extra indirection with the pointer, both returning it and using it.  It's likely you left that out when you tried to switch from one to the other, leading to the invalid message you received, but it's impossible to tell without more information.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer, just some code that helps the discussion.**

```
static int ga[4] = { 49, 49, 42, 00 };
int (*get_ptr_ga())[4]
{
    return &ga;
}

int (&get_ref_ga())[4]
{
    return ga;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int (*p) [4] = get_ptr_ga();
    int (&r) [4] = get_ref_ga();
    char sz[4];
    sz[0] = (*p)[2];
    sz[1] = r[2];
    sz[2] = '\n';
    sz[3] = 0;
    printf(sz);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`int &func;` is a reference, and `int *func;` is a pointer. Because the first is a reference, it needs to be initialized to an int l-value, such as `a` if it was declared `int a;`, and cannot be assigned. The latter is a pointer which can be initialized/assigned another `int*` such as `&a` if it were declared `int a;`.

Comment: While that's true (and so, personally, I don't think it needs a -1), that doesn't really have anything to do with the OP's code. Those are function declarations, returning a reference to/a pointer to an array of 5 ints.